# MIC not working due to USB bandwidth

Tags: debian, centos, kernel, linux-mint, usb-audio

Using debian and centos, i get the same error when plugging my USB mic in. In Windows (xp thru 8.1) it works fine.

```
[ 304.237543] usb 2-1.6.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 305.220785] usb 2-1.6.2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[ 305.331189] usb 2-1.6.2: New USB device found, idVendor=a012, idProduct=b012
[ 305.331195] usb 2-1.6.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 305.331198] usb 2-1.6.2: Product: DYNEX USB MIC Device
[ 305.331201] usb 2-1.6.2: Manufacturer: DYNEX
[ 305.331204] usb 2-1.6.2: SerialNumber: 12000002
[ 305.338744] input: DYNEX DYNEX USB MIC Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6.2/2-1.6.2:1.2/input/input21
[ 305.338893] hid-generic 0003:A012:B012.000A: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.00 Device [DYNEX DYNEX USB MIC Device] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6.2/input2
[ 305.366189] cannot submit urb 0, error -28: not enough bandwidth


[ 304.237543] usb 2-1.6.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 305.220785] usb 2-1.6.2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[ 305.331189] usb 2-1.6.2: New USB device found, idVendor=a012, idProduct=b012
[ 305.331195] usb 2-1.6.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 305.331198] usb 2-1.6.2: Product: DYNEX USB MIC Device
[ 305.331201] usb 2-1.6.2: Manufacturer: DYNEX
[ 305.331204] usb 2-1.6.2: SerialNumber: 12000002
[ 305.338744] input: DYNEX DYNEX USB MIC Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6.2/2-1.6.2:1.2/input/input21
[ 305.338893] hid-generic 0003:A012:B012.000A: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.00 Device [DYNEX DYNEX USB MIC Device] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6.2/input2
[ 305.366189] cannot submit urb 0, error -28: not enough bandwidth
```

What i noticed is that with centos, the issue existed from the start, with debian, the mic initially worked until i allowed the update process to continue. after rebooting, i began to see this issue. I assume due to the output that this is due to a kernel change, possibly with the ehci/uhci but i'm not positive.

The MIC on my webcam works (although a little delayed due to some other errors)  and a line in mic works, im only having this issue with this particular USB mic.

Attempting some other solutions, i completely removed pulseaudio as many blame world hunger on pulse, but even with just Alsa, the problem still remained. This furthers my belief that the issue is with the kernel and/or modules as opposed to other software.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Is this the only USB device connected to your computer? If not, try to disconnect others.

Comment: the webcam is usb; i attempted disconnecting both it and the mic and plugging them back in. the usb cam comes up fine (mic and video) the dynex mic gives the error above. for further info they're plugged into usb 2 ports

Comment: can anyone tell me why my question was down-voted? wrong forum to ask in?

Comment: Not my downvote, maybe someone thought it is a vague, unhelpful question. You could try the linux-usb mailing list for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not previously used distributions like this, im a long time slackware/linuxfromscratch user and I was under the impression that these used kernels with a multitude of modules to ensure full compatibility (especially considering they recommend against rolling your own kernel) I downloaded the latest from kernel.org and compiled it, it resolved the problem as soon as I booted it. I haven't had time to dig into what specifically caused the issue (i think snd_usb) but the new kernel definitely took care of it.

to add a little info to the original, i rebuilt the system around 7 times and noticed that upon initial boot after install the mic worked. it would stop working after the first reboot 5/7 times. 2/7 times it was dead on boot with the above errors. this is without loading any software/updates in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.The solution was to enable flag `CONFIG_USB_EHCI_TT_NEWSCHED` in Linux kernel.

Source article: https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/Problem-with-usb-audio-capture/m-p/357810